# ByRef argument type mismatch when calling function

Tags: excel, vba

I get this error with no apparent reason. The code isn't even executed and the error message is thrown.

```
Dim aggregateProductionWbName As String
Dim aggregateProductionWb as Workbook
aggregateProductionWbName = "Plano agregado de produção Teste"
Set aggregateProductionWb = Workbooks(aggregateProductionWbName)
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt("Sheet", aggregateProductionWb)
```

The second argument of seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt is pointed.
Here's seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt function:

```
Public Function seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt(sheetName As String, wb As Workbook, Optional newSheetPos As Variant) As Worksheet
Dim wbSheetNames() As String
wbSheetNames = getSheetNamesOfWb(wb)
If isStringInArray(sheetName, wbSheetNames) Then
Else
    If IsMissing(newSheetPos) Then
        wb.Sheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    Else
        wb.Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(newSheetPos)
    End If
    wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName
End If
Set seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt = wb.Worksheets(sheetName)
End Function
```

getSheetNamesOfWb declaration:

```
Public Function getSheetNamesOfWb(wb As Workbook) As String()
```

isStringInArray declaration:

```
Public Function isStringInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include only the declaration line for `getSheetNamesOfWb()` and `isStringInArray()`.

Comment: The edition is done.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the file extension like e.g. `.xslm` to the `gateProductionWbName` string assignment?

Comment: I've seen this a couple of times when the argument types clearly match ... try (temporarily) changing the type of `wb` from `Workbook` to `Variant` then Debug > Compile and actually run your project if it is in a runnable state, then change it back to `Workbook` and compile again

Comment: When the error occurs, which variable gets highlighted?

Comment: aggregateProductionWb, in the `seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt` call.

Comment: I did what @JohnM told. Once I change the variable type to Variant and compile, the same error is thrown in another variable, in the calling of another function.

Comment: How about if you save, close, and re-open?  Does it help?

Comment: Try changing all of the arguments to `Variant`, compile, then replace them with the right types. If that doesn't work, try deleting (copy it first!) the whole `seeIfSheetIsCreatedAndIfNotCreateOneAndReturnIt` procedure then compile, replace the procedure and see. Finally, if that doesn't work, export a copy of the entire Module, delete the Module, compile, then re-import the Module

Comment: I tried saving and closing but didn't work.

Comment: Did you maybe rename something in your VBProject to "Workbook" ?

Comment: I've also tried what @JohnM said, didn't work. First, when I changed the arguments to variant and compiled, no errors were thrown, but when 
I replaced them again with the right types, I got the same error. Then when I tried deleting things, everytime I compiled the code errors of not defined functions were thrown, when I putted the deleted parts again it thrown the same error again.

Comment: @TimWilliams, no, I did a research to see if that was the case but not.

Comment: Can't replicate the problem, so there's something you've not shown us here.  Can you share a workbook which reproduces the error?

Comment: How many Modules do you have in your project? If only a small number, export and remove them all, compile, save your workbook and close and re-open Excel, and then re-import all Modules. Or, do you happen to use [MZ-Tools](https://www.mztools.com/v8/mztools8.aspx)? If so, try the Clean Project feature?

Comment: Yes, here's a link to a wb that replicates the problem.https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhB93GFVotAImRSTnut0PjMYUhzK?e=Md0Nov.
My excel has solver add-in installed.

Comment: This link is not accessible unless signed in to onedrive....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From your posted workbook)

```
Dim aggregateProductionWb, stockManagementWb As Workbook
```

VBA requires *every variable* to have a type - unless you want a `Variant` - so you need to write this as

```
Dim aggregateProductionWb As Workbook, stockManagementWb As Workbook
```

This shows why we need to see your actual code to help with debugging....